# SQL - Insert constant based on the presence of categorical value

Tags: mysql, sql, left-join, coalesce, cross-join

I have a table like the following in MySQL:

| ID | COMPONENT | AMOUNT |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | C1 | 12 |
| 123 | C2 | 15.5 |
| 123 | C3 | 13 |
| 234 | C1 | 544 |
| 234 | C2 | 546 |
| 445 | C1 | 142 |
| 334 | C1 | 13 |

And would like to obtain something like this using an SQL SELECT:

| ID | COMPONENT | AMOUNT |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | C1 | 12 |
| 123 | C2 | 15.5 |
| 123 | C3 | 13 |
| 234 | C1 | 544 |
| 234 | C2 | 546 |
| 234 | C3 | 0 |
| 445 | C1 | 142 |
| 445 | C2 | 0 |
| 445 | C3 | 0 |
| 334 | C1 | 13 |
| 334 | C2 | 0 |
| 334 | C3 | 0 |

Meaning I would like to show rows with AMOUNT 0 for the components that do not exist for a given ID.

Comment: Do you mean add these rows to the result of a SELECT, or actually INSERT new rows into the table?

Comment: Using a SELECT statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a `CROSS` join of the distinct `ID`s to the distinct `COMPONENT`s and a `LEFT` join to the table:

```
SELECT i.ID, c.COMPONENT,
       COALESCE(t.AMOUNT, 0) AMOUNT
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT ID FROM tablename) i
CROSS JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT COMPONENT FROM tablename) c
LEFT JOIN tablename t ON t.ID = i.ID AND t.COMPONENT = c.COMPONENT
ORDER BY i.ID, c.COMPONENT;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=cdb77861a3f88d94ef2f664f85741066).

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to do it:

```
select t1.id, 
       t1.component, 
       IFNULL(t2.amount,0) amount 
from (
     select a.id, b.component from table1 a
     left join (select distinct component from table1) b on 1=1
     group by a.id, b.component 
     ) t1
left join table1 t2 on t1.id=t2.id and t1.component=t2.component
order by t1.id, t1.component;
```

**Explained:** Step 1: The subselect puts together all unique combinations of id and components regardless of the amount values. Step 2: Do a left join to calculate the amount for each id/component combination.

This query works if you don't have a duplicate combination of id/component in your table. If you do have multiple values for each combination you can use an aggregate function like `group by` on the first two columns, and `sum()` on the amount column.

**The result:**

| id | component | amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | C1 | 12 |
| 123 | C2 | 15.5 |
| 123 | C3 | 13 |
| 234 | C1 | 544 |
| 234 | C2 | 546 |
| 234 | C3 | 0 |
| 334 | C1 | 13 |
| 334 | C2 | 0 |
| 334 | C3 | 0 |
| 445 | C1 | 142 |
| 445 | C2 | 0 |
| 445 | C3 | 0 |

**Dummy data:**

```
CREATE TABLE table1 (
  id int(11),
  component varchar(10),
  amount float(5,1)
  );
  
INSERT INTO table1 VALUES
    (123, 'C1', 12),
    (123, 'C2', 15.5),
    (123, 'C3', 13),
    (234, 'C1', 544),
    (234, 'C2', 546),
    (445, 'C1', 142),
    (334, 'C1', 13);
```

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/cbdKPTJKxuJ84LgPGxp2Tj/1)